# Почему я не могу удалить атрибут у ссылки

Tags: jquery

Есть код

```
$("#d3").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('my3d');
    $("a").removeAttr("class");
    $(".main-cube").css("top", "10%");
    $(".cube").css({width: "95vw", height: "45vh"});
    $(".side").css({position: "static", transform: "none", width: "95vw", height: "90vh"});
});
```

В нем конкретно мне нужно удалить у ссылок атрибут class, чтобы он не активировал вращение фигуры. То есть, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку ничего не происходило. Но почему то удаление атрибута не работает. При нажатии, к примеру, на aa с классом link2 запускается вращение фигуры (по другому jQuery коду), несмотря ни на какие мои колдовства. Как так-то???

Вот код HTML к которому я хочу применить удаление:

```
<ul class="main-menu loft-mnu">
    <li><a class="link1" href="#side1">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a class="link2" href="#side2">О компании</a></li>
    <li><a class="link3" href="#side3">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a class="link4" href="#side4">Заказать сайт</a></li>
    <li><a class="link5" href="#side5">Цены</a></li>
    <li><a class="link6" href="#side6">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

"Другой код"

```
 $(".link2").on("click", function() {
    $('.side')
        .animate({ width: "600px" }, 1000 )
        .animate({ height: "600px" }, 1000 );
    $(".cube").css({width: "600px", height: "600px", left: "0"});
    setTimeout (function () {
        $('.cube').css("transform", "rotate3d(0,1,0,270deg)");
    }, 2500 );
    setTimeout (function () {
        $(".cube").css({width: "95vw", height: "45vh"});
        $('.main-cube').css({top: "10%", perspective: "2000px"});
        $('.side2')
            .animate({ width: "95vw" }, 1000 )
            .animate({ height: "90vh" }, 1000 );
    }, 5000 );
});
```

Comment: "удаление аттрибута не работает" - откуда Вы знаете? обработчик на клики ссылок уже навешан?

Comment: потому что моя фигура все равно продолжает вращаться

Comment: может быть следует показать "другой" код? или Вы считаете, что здесь сидят телепаты?

Comment: обработчик привязывается к элементу, а не к классу. После привязки все равно есть у элемента какой-то класс или нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).on("click", ".link2", function() { ...`

*Update*

Ну добавьте в обработчик:

```
$(".link2").on("click", function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("link2"))
    return;

  ...
}
```

*Update 2*

Верните, пожалуйста, вопрос к первоначальному виду и задайте другой.

И будьте добры, не пишите

`return (someNumber % 2 === 0) ? true : false;`

и

`if (isEven(count) === false) {`

Пишите

```
var isEven = function(someNumber) {
  return someNumber % 2 === 0;
};
if (!isEven(count)) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Какой смысл строки

`$(".main-menu a").attr("class");`?

Comment: но тогда не работает вращение. у меня в коде будет 3 мерная фигура, которая при нажатии по самому верхнему коду раскладывается в двухмерную. так вот трехмерная должна вращаться и разворачиваться по последнему коду, а у 2 мерной должен удаляться атрибут a class.

Comment: Годится, спасибо большое!

Comment: интересный вопрос:) а как ему назад аттрибут класса вернуть?

Comment: @ВладимирАбрамович в какой момент?

Comment: В момент повторного нажатия на #d3. Сейчас я размещу его вверху дополнительный код

Comment: А можно ли вернуть мой первоначальный вид вопроса как то тут, или надо по памяти вспоминать? Или можно своими словами заново написать? Код я восстановил

Comment: @ВладимирАбрамович Если Вы пойдете в историю правок (щелкните на строчку "изменён 25 минут назад" под Вашим вопросом), то увидите, что там можно сделать "откат" на предыдущие версии вопроса.